# Магазин-блог wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как реализовать сайт-блог, в котором также продаются товары?

Например, человек заходит на главную страницу сайта, и перед ним идут статьи. Также он может перейти в другой раздел сайта - "магазин" и заказать там какие либо товары.

Возможно ли такое реализовать, и как это сделать? И какой плагин мне в этом поможет?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте плагин woocommerce.

Comment: Спасибо, но насколько мне известно данный плагин добавит форму оплаты на всех страницах, в том числе и на статьи (в которых ничего не продается), или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Из коробки можно добавить просто страницы корзины и оплаты

Comment: Спасибо, завтра попробую добавить этот плагин.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, будут ли правильно отображаться карточки товаров при использовании сторонней темы WordPress (не от woocommerce и не от WordPress)? Если нет - то как настроить правильное отображение?

Comment: В любую тему можно интегрировать поддержку работы с вукоммерс